# Radio button value not passing to variable and stop the submit

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've looked at the other radio button questions here and just can't troubleshoot why my radio button value is not being passed to the variable or why it's stopping the submit.

When I comment out the script/markup/php related to "pet" the submit happens and I can see the query string in my address bar, but when I comment back in it doesn't do anything, no errors, just doesn't do anything.

**Offending script**

```
var radio = document.getElementsByName('pet');

        for (var i = 0, length = radio.length; i < length; i++) {
            if (radio[i].checked) {
            // do whatever you want with the checked radio
                var pet = (radio[i].value);

        // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
        break;
    }
}
```

**Entire script**

```
function validateFormOnSubmit(contact) {
    reason = "";
    reason += validateName(contact.name);
    reason += validateEmail(contact.email);
    reason += validatePhone(contact.phone);
    reason += validatePet(contact.pet);
    reason += validateNumber(contact.number);
    reason += validateDisclaimer(contact.disclaimer);

    console.log(reason);
    if (reason.length > 0) {

        return false;
    } else {
        alert("Test alert"); // Show some loading image and submit form
        submitFormAjax();
    }
}

// validate required fields
function validateName(name) {
    var error = "";

    if (name.value.length == 0) {
        name.style.background = 'Red';
        document.getElementById('name-error').innerHTML = "The required field has not been filled in";
        var error = "1";
    } else {
        name.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('name-error').innerHTML = '';
    }
    return error;
}

// validate email as required field and format
function trim(s) {
    return s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');
}

function validateEmail(email) {
    var error = "";
    var temail = trim(email.value); // value of field with whitespace trimmed off
    var emailFilter = /^[^@]+@[^@.]+\.[^@]*\w\w$/;
    var illegalChars = /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\"\[\]]/;

    if (email.value == "") {
        email.style.background = 'Red';
        document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML = "Please enter an email address.";
        var error = "2";
    } else if (!emailFilter.test(temail)) { //test email for illegal characters
        email.style.background = 'Red';
        document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email address.";
        var error = "3";
    } else if (email.value.match(illegalChars)) {
        email.style.background = 'Red';
        var error = "4";
        document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML = "Email contains invalid characters.";
    } else {
        email.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML = '';
    }
    return error;
}

// validate phone for required and format
function validatePhone(phone) {
    var error = "";
    var stripped = phone.value.replace(/[\(\)\.\-\ ]/g, '');

    if (phone.value == "") {
        document.getElementById('phone-error').innerHTML = "Please enter a phone number";
        phone.style.background = 'Red';
        var error = '6';
    } else if (isNaN(parseInt(stripped))) {
        var error = "5";
        document.getElementById('phone-error').innerHTML = "The phone number contains illegal characters.";
        phone.style.background = 'Red';
    } else if (stripped.length < 10) {
        var error = "6";
        document.getElementById('phone-error').innerHTML = "The phone number is too short.";
        phone.style.background = 'Red';
    } else {
        phone.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('phone-error').innerHTML = '';
    }
    return error;
}

function validatePet(pet) {
    if ((contact.pet[0].checked == false) && (contact.pet[1].checked == false) && (contact.pet[2].checked == false)) {
        document.getElementById('pet-error').innerHTML = "Pet required";
        var error = "2";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('pet-error').innerHTML = '';
    }
    return error;
}

function validateNumber(number) {
    var num = document.forms["contact"]["number"];
    var y = num.value;
    if (!isNaN(y)) {

        //alert('va');

        if (y < 1 || y > 50) {
            //Wrong
            number.style.background = 'Red';
            document.getElementById("number-error").innerHTML = "Must be between 1 and 50.";
            var error = "10";
        } else {
            //Correct
            number.style.background = 'White';
            document.getElementById("number-error").innerHTML = "";
        }
        return error;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("number-error").innerHTML = "Must be a number.";
        var error = "3";
    }
    return error;
}

function validateDisclaimer(disclaimer) {
    var error = "";

    if (document.getElementById("disclaimer").checked === false) {
        document.getElementById('disclaimer-error').innerHTML = "Required";
        var error = "4";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('disclaimer-error').innerHTML = '';
        var disclaimer = document.getElementById("disclaimer").checked;
    }
    return error;
}

function submitFormAjax() {
    var xmlhttp= window.XMLHttpRequest ?
        new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText); // Here is the response
    }

    var name = document.getElementById('name').innerHTML;
    var nickname = document.getElementById('nickname').innerHTML;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').innerHTML;
    var number = document.getElementById('number').innerHTML;
    var radio = document.getElementsByName('pet');

        for (var i = 0, length = radio.length; i < length; i++) {
            if (radio[i].checked) {
            // do whatever you want with the checked radio
                var pet = (radio[i].value);

        // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
        break;
    }
}

    xmlhttp.open("GET","form.php?name=" + name + "&nickname=" + nickname + "&email=" + email + "&phone=" + phone + "&pet=" + pet + "&number=" + number + "&disclaimer=" + disclaimer, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" onsubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit(this)" action="form.php" method="get">
    <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="name" id="name" tabindex="1" autofocus />
        <div id="name-error" class="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Nickname</label>
        <input placeholder="Nickname" type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" tabindex="2" autofocus />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="3" autofocus />
        <div id="email-error" class="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Phone</label>
        <input placeholder="Phone" type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" tabindex="4" autofocus />
        <div id="phone-error" class="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>I prefer</label>
        <input type="radio" name="pet" id="Dogs" tabindex="5" autofocus />Dogs
        <input type="radio" name="pet" id="Cats" tabindex="6" autofocus />Cats
        <input type="radio" name="pet" id="Neither" tabindex="7" autofocus />Neither
        <div id="pet-error" class="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>My favorite number between 1 and 50</label>
        <input placeholder="Favorite number between 1 and 50" type="text" name="number" id="number" tabindex="8" autofocus />
        <div id="number-error" class="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Disclaimer</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="disclaimer" id="disclaimer" tabindex="9" autofocus />I confirm that all the above information is true.
        <div id="disclaimer-error" class="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="10">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$nickname = $_GET['nickname'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$phone = $_GET['phone'];
$pet = $_GET['pet'];
$number = $_GET['number'];
$disclaimer = $_GET['disclaimer'];
$from = 'From: Test From'; 
$to = 'euteneier@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello';
$message = "This is a message.";

if ($_GET['submit']) {               
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $message)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
} 
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: try putting value attributes in your radio button elements

Comment: Have you checked your PHP logs? Your Javascript doesn't seem to handle AJAX failure, which would explain why you don't see anything.

Comment: You're not setting `disclaimer` in `submitFormAjax()` btw and shouldn't `+ email, +` be `+ email +`?

Comment: I haven't check the PHP logs. I'm new to PHP, how do I check them?Radio button values = didn't work. Disclaimer's value is set in the disclaimer validation function. @kingkero GOOD CATCH. Sadly that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Here is the test site. http://first_books.justineuteneier.com/contact.php

Comment: Your current contact.php doesn't have any radio selections.

Comment: I just commented them out to test. Try it now.

Comment: Should I move the pet variable outside the AJAX function, similar to disclaimer?

Comment: While trying to submit your form (now with radio buttons added back in) I notice that your validation script is console.logging undefinedundefinedundefined - it's stopping your form from submitting, so I would start troubleshooting the validation script

Comment: how did you see that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with help from @ToniAlmeida. It needed to have

```
var error = "";
```

added to the validatePet() function

Relevent script:

```
function validatePet(pet) {
    var error = "";

    if ((contact.pet[0].checked == false) && (contact.pet[1].checked == false) && (contact.pet[2].checked == false)) {
        document.getElementById('pet-error').innerHTML = "Pet required";
        var error = "2";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('pet-error').innerHTML = '';
    }
    return error;
}

var radio = document.getElementsByName('pet');

        for (var i = 0, length = radio.length; i < length; i++) {
            if (radio[i].checked) {
            // do whatever you want with the checked radio
                var pet = (radio[i].value);

        // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
        break;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","form.php?name=" + name + "&nickname=" + nickname + "&email=" + email + "&phone=" + phone + "&pet=" + pet + "&number=" + number + "&disclaimer=" + disclaimer, true);
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `value="Dog\cat\etc"` attribute to the radio button, which will get sent if you post the form.

Comment: put `print_r($_POST);` at the top if your script to see all the values that have been posted to the server.

Comment: I'm using GET on the form and for the AJAX, does that matter?

Comment: My bad, chabge `$_POST` to `$_GET`

Comment: That didn't do anything. I click the "Send" button and it just sits there. I'm assuming you meant at the top of my PHP script.

Comment: Interesting. When I comment out the bit about pets, it prints the array like you mentioned. There is just something in the pets scripts that is causing a problem.